# Should I create a model for classes that use db or just make database operations directly

Tags: database, model-view-controller

I have designed my website using the MVC model and I have been making all my database business in the model. I saw a code on how to make an  user class on one website and it makes a lot of database operation to fetch user permissions and user roles, the problem is if I use this class as it is, it will break my MVC structure because SQL operations will be made outside a model class. So how do I use this class? Should I

- create a database connection object in my controller and pass it as argument to the user class,
- just go ahead and query MySQL in this user class or
- create a model class for my user class but this won't make sense since this class is not a controller

Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the meaning of ALC?

Comment: I just edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your third option, you don't need to have a controller for every model you create. Since user certainly is an entity of your relational database model, it's natural to create a model for it.

And this model would be a good place to put all this persmissions and roles code. This way your controllers could ask the user model if one user has or has not permission for a specific action or wich is it's role.

Comment: so its ok for me to create object of `UserModel()` in user class @Daniel

Comment: Yes, sure. Or you could put all the logic of your user class in UserModel and just instantiate it wherever you need. This way you don't need the user class at all, it would be replaced by UserModel.